# .htaccess disabling deflate for one particular php file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, deflate

we are deflating the php files for compression, performance, etc.

the .htaccess file syntax goes like this:

```
<Files *.php>
     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

now we have one file getsong.php which basically serves mp3s. i dont want this file to be inflated because our flash mp3 player seems to have problem in un-compressing the served mp3 and is not giving correct play duration of the mp3 file,etc.

as a quick-fix, i would like to change this `<files>` directive so that it excludes the getsong.php. i've tried various regular expressions but failed badly. can u plz tell me how to write regular expression for this within the files directive or should i use filesmatch?

any other ideas on how to handle this problem are also welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something like this to work:

```
<Files *.php>
     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
<Files youronefile.php>
     SetOutputFilter NONE (or something)
</Files>
```

If that doesn't work, remember to use `<FilesMatch>` with your regular expression :)

Comment: yeah it worked.. actually I hate regular expressions.. so i prefer doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Try that for your `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "(.*[^getsong])\.php">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

I assume that you use Apache >= 1.3

// **EDIT**:
just did it the wrong way :) :p.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure this matches any file consisting of at least one character of which the last is not g,e,t,s,o,n, or g, followed by '.php'.